# how to get latest email from outlook interop email

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-interop

```
   outlook.MAPIFolder selectedFolder = m_applicationObject.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
                        string expMessage = "Your current folder is " + selectedFolder.Name + ".\n";
                        string itemMessage = "Item is unknown.";
                        try
                        {
                            if (m_applicationObject.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
                            {
                                Object selObject = m_applicationObject.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
                                if (selObject is outlook.MailItem)
                                {
                                    outlook.MailItem mailItem = (selObject as outlook.MailItem);
                                    itemMessage = " The subject is " + mailItem.Subject + ". \n";
                                    itemMessage += " The Email is " + getSenderEmailAddress(mailItem)  + ".\n";
                                    itemMessage += " The name is " + mailItem.SenderName + ".\n";
                                    itemMessage += " The Desc is " + mailItem.Body  + ".\n"; 
                                    //body consist of too many emails and its replies. is there any way i can extract latest email content from mailitem.Body
                                    //  mailItem.Display(false);
                                }
                            }
                     }
```

In above code i am extracting email details from outlook addin 
body consist of too many emails and its replies. is there any way i can extract latest email content from `mailitem.Body`

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. There is no easy and trivial way of extracting the message body for the latest reply.

However, you can use the following ways to extract the latest reply.

1. Extract every email/reply by going through the conversation. The [MailItem.GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method obtains a `Conversation` object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs, for example:

```
void DemoConversation() 
{ 
 object selectedItem = 
 Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1]; 
 // This example uses only 
 // MailItem. Other item types such as 
 // MeetingItem and PostItem can participate 
 // in the conversation. 
 if (selectedItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 // Cast selectedItem to MailItem. 
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
 selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
 // Determine the store of the mail item. 
 Outlook.Folder folder = mailItem.Parent 
 as Outlook.Folder; 
 Outlook.Store store = folder.Store; 
 if (store.IsConversationEnabled == true) 
 { 
 // Obtain a Conversation object. 
 Outlook.Conversation conv = 
 mailItem.GetConversation(); 
 // Check for null Conversation. 
 if (conv != null) 
 { 
 // Obtain Table that contains rows 
 // for each item in the conversation. 
 Outlook.Table table = conv.GetTable(); 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items Count: " + 
 table.GetRowCount().ToString()); 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Table:"); 
 while (!table.EndOfTable) 
 { 
 Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow(); 
 Debug.WriteLine(nextRow["Subject"] 
 + " Modified: " 
 + nextRow["LastModificationTime"]); 
 } 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Root:"); 
 // Obtain root items and enumerate the conversation. 
 Outlook.SimpleItems simpleItems 
 = conv.GetRootItems(); 
 foreach (object item in simpleItems) 
 { 
 // In this example, enumerate only MailItem type. 
 // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
 // can appear in the conversation. 
 if (item is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 Outlook.MailItem mail = item 
 as Outlook.MailItem; 
 Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
 mail.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
 string msg = mail.Subject 
 + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
 Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
 } 
 // Call EnumerateConversation 
 // to access child nodes of root items. 
 EnumerateConversation(item, conv); 
 } 
 } 
 } 
 } 
} 


void EnumerateConversation(object item, 
 Outlook.Conversation conversation) 
{ 
 Outlook.SimpleItems items = 
 conversation.GetChildren(item); 
 if (items.Count > 0) 
 { 
 foreach (object myItem in items) 
 { 
 // In this example, enumerate only MailItem type. 
 // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
 // can appear in the conversation. 
 if (myItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
 myItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
 Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
 mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
 string msg = mailItem.Subject 
 + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
 Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
 } 
 // Continue recursion. 
 EnumerateConversation(myItem, conversation); 
 } 
 } 
}
```

2. Find the signature place and get a substring before the signature starts.

The default folder where Outlook email signature files are located is:

- Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures
```

- Windows 10/ 8 / 7 / Vista:

```
 C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

3. Try using regular expressions to extract the first part.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered several type, see, for example - [Only get the latest reply text in an Outlook Email using VSTO and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757154/only-get-the-latest-reply-text-in-an-outlook-email-using-vsto-and-c-sharp).

You cannot do that even in theory: imagine a user typing at the top of the message (e.g. "see below") and then inserting/deleting various pieces in the message body below (I do that all the time). You are lucky if the font color is different.

You can try to compare the original with the new and figure out the diff (see the link above).